# SQL database using Visual Basic 6

Tags: sql

```
sql = "insert into reservation (train_no,trainame,from,to,name1,age) values(" &
      Val(lbl3.Caption) & ",' " & lbl4.Caption & "','" & findtrain.srce.Text &
      "','" & findtrain.dstn.Text & "','" & Form3.Text1.Text & "'," &
      Val(Form3.Text3.Text) & ")"
```

What's the syntax error here ?

Comment: Your sequence `& ",' " &` probably shouldn't have the space after the single quote (it belongs before it).  However, that's not a syntactic problem.  You aren't enclosing either `Val(lbl3.Caption)` or `Val(Form3.Text3.Text)` in quotes -- unless that's what the `Val` function does.  You should worry about SQL injection throughout.

Comment: Add a line showing the contents of `sql` in a MsgBox to see what the final output is after the statement is built.

Comment: Given what you've written, I don't see a syntax error *but* the values embedded in the statement could easily cause syntax errors.  Any apostrophe (single quote) in one of the strings would wreck your syntax.

Comment: Bad use for insert data into a database... use paremeters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use parameters with ADO? it will be easier to debug.

```
 Public Function Insert(ByVal Values As String) As Integer
    Dim sCon As String = ConnectionString()
    Dim sel As String

    sel = "INSERT INTO " & NombreTabla & _
        "(Columns) " & _
        "VALUES " & _
        "(@Params) " & _
        "SELECT @@Identity"

    Using con As New SqlConnection(sCon)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sel, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Params", Values)


        con.Open()
        Dim t As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        con.Close()

        Return t
    End Using
End Function
```